# Cannot start Metro server for React Native

Tags: react-native

When I run the development environment the app is launching but it's not implementing the changes I have made. Even if I try to reload the app it's not working and even Dev Menu is also giving the error[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5LjN.png)

I tried restarting VS Code and reloading the app. Its showing "Cannot connect to Metro Server"

Comment: Seems like a connection issue, try to see on what IP your dev server runs and connect to that IP in the `Expo Go` app

Comment: Your screenshot just showing that your application cannot connect to metro.
Verify in your terminal that metro is running.
How do you start metro?

Comment: I encountered this problem when using a Mac and a physical device (iPhone). I need to disable WiFi and Network on my iPhone, connect via cable to my mac and use "share internet via cable" feature. In this way the iPhone was forced to use the internet of my mac and metro connected properly. Check if you're connected to the same internet (WiFi) and if you give internet permission to your app.

Answer (score 0):

if you are having this problem in your android emulator. it's as a result of either restarting the terminal in you work space. you can fix this by first going to your device manager, stop the emulator from running. in the action corner of the device manager click on the pencil icon which takes you to the virtual device configuration. edit you AVD name and save ..click on the finish button. restart you vs code and restart your emulator this should resolve the problem.